# Is the function $(x^2+y^2)\sin{(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2})}$ differentiable at the point $(0,0)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

EDIT: The question specifies that $f(0,0)=0$ in a piecewise.

For the first few parts of a question, I have used the definition of partial derivatives to show that $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}$ and $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}$ both exist at the point $(0,0)$ and are equal to $0$. I have also found the partial derivatives for $f$ at a point away from $(0,0)$ using normal differentiation rules like product, quotient and chain rule, and have shown that $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$ by showing its limit diverges as we approach $(0,0)$.

Have I made a mistake so far in my reasoning and working? If not, I would like to take on the last part of this question, which asks us to determine if $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.

For this last part, I know two theorems:

1: "If $f$ is differentiable at some point, then all of its partial derivatives exist at that point and its derivative is the jacobian matrix of the function".

2: "If all of the partial derivatives of $f$ exists and are continuous on some set, then $f$ is differentiable on that set"

Could I use any of these here?

I know we could also use the definition of differentiability to calculuate the limit of and prove the existence of an affine approximation, but I was just wondering if there was any other way to do the question.

Comment: You have checked that $\partial f/\partial x$ is not continuous, so you cannot use (2) to conclude that the function would be differentiable at the origin. You have verified that the partial derivatives exist, so you cannot use  (1) to conclude that the function is not differentiable at the origin. Therefore neither (1) nor (2) is conclusive, and you are forced to use the definition of differentiability (or some other tool unknown to us). Them's the breaks. What did you expect? It is an essential part of math education to raise awareness of the limitations of the simple methods.

Comment: Would the converse/contrapositive of any of the theorems above be true, and if so, help me out?

Comment: Correct. As Anne Bauval explained you can use your work on the partial derivatives to the extent that only one alternative for the Jacobian remains. Simply show that the resulting approximation is good enough. Hop to it!

Comment: With the definition of differentiability right?

Comment: We already milked out everything we could from the contrapositives. I guess that the whole point of this exercise is to show that the converses do not hold in general. Yes. The way I see it you are expected to apply the definition of differentiability. But you can use what you know about the partial derivatives to predict what the linear derivative must be (= the all zeros function).

Comment: I see. Thank you all. I will try that out.

Comment: I assume that you got the partial derivatives:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2x\left(\sin(\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}) - \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}\cos(\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2})\right)$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 2y\left(\sin(\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}) - \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}\cos(\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2})\right)$$

Comment: Yes, that is what I got.

Answer (score 2):

Since **you already showed that $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}$ and $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}$ both exist at the point $(0,0)$ and are equal to $0$**, your theorem 1 indicates that if $f$ is differentiable at this point, its differential is necessarily the zero map.

Therefore, by definition of the differential, $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ if and only if
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{|f(x,y)-f(0,0)-0x-0y|}{\|(x,y)\|}=0,$$
i.e.
$$\lim_{r\to0}\frac{r^2\sin(1/r^2)}r=0,$$
which is indeed the case since $|\sin|\le1$.